# My Ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm learning Ajax, which is great, but I encounter some difficulties on the implementation of it.
I would like to call a fadeOut the element #group_box when a user click on a button #rem_req_btn.

My code is working only on the first element of my list, but not the others one. I've try to add the group id in the div but is not working.

Anyone can help me to find the better way to achieve this action ?

Index group :

```
<% @my_groups.each do |group| %>
  <div id="group_box">
    <%= render 'group', group: group %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

_group :

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 style="margin-top:5px; text-align:center">
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Test
      </div>

      <div class="panel-footer" style="height: 50px; padding:7px;">
        <div class="btn btn-default">
          <i class="fa fa-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></i>      
        </div>
        <%- unless group.main? %>
          <%= link_to rem_req_group_path(group), method: :patch, data: {confirm: "Etes vous sur de vouloir sortir de ce groupe ?"}, id: "rem_req_btn", remote: true do %>
            <div class="btn btn-danger pull-right">
              <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Ajax file:

```
$('#rem_req_btn').bind('ajax:success', function() {
   $(this).closest('#group_box').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following

**Index Template**
`<div id="group_box">` to `<div id="group_box#{group.id}">`

**Remove JS code from your index page**

$('#rem_req_btn').bind('ajax:success', function() {
   $(this).closest('#group_box').fadeOut();
});

Create a `.js.erb` template at the level of `index.erb` with name equal the action name. eg. if `rem_req_group_path(group)` is mapped to  `rem_req_group` action in your controller where the request is landing when you click the link then the name would be `rem_req_group.js.erb`

Now in `rem_req_group.js.erb` write following

`#("#group_box#{params[:id]}").fadeOut();`

Comment: Hi, @AmitPatel, thanks for your answer, it was really clear. I follow your explaination and it's working !!! My mistake was to forget the .erb in my file. So my ajax didn't understand the <%@group.id%>
Thanks for all, have a good day

Answer (score 0):

you cannot repeat the id attribute in html, means you can but you shouldn't... id should be unique no doubt jQuery is picking only the first section... please try using class instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've try your solution but is still not working. I also tried to add an <%=group.id%> into the div but it's not working anymore. Any idea of what can be incorrect ?